# Вывод текста из тег span с обрезкой окончания

Tags: javascript

Как сделать вывод текста из span и обрезать окончание у каждого span а также разделить каждый span запятой, через JavaScript?

```js
var a = $('#tegs_tagsinput').first().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 1;
}).text().slice(0, -3);
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tegs_tagsinput" style="display:none">
  <span class="tag"><span>1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
  <span class="tag"><span>2&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
  <span class="tag"><span>3&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

С помощью `slice` убрали последние 3 символа из всего текста, а как убрать по 3 символа из каждого `span` и разделить из запятыми? чтобы в конечном результате мы получили 1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем все `span` с классом tag, берем текст первого `span` внутри, очищаем от пробелов:

```js
var a = [];
$('#tegs_tagsinput .tag').each(function() {
  a.push($(this).find('span').eq(0).text().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
});
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = a.join(',');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tegs_tagsinput" style="display:none">
  <span class="tag"><span>1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
  <span class="tag"><span>2&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
  <span class="tag"><span>3&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно удалить 2 последних символа каждого span и получить массив данных, с которым вы уже можете работать свободно. Если же нужно оставлять только первый знак, а знаков в span будет много, то вам нужно сделать другие условия slice, например: `slice(0, 1)`.

```js
var string = [], i = 0;
while(document.getElementsByClassName('tag')[i]) {
 string.push(document.getElementsByClassName('tag')[i].firstChild.textContent.slice(0, -2));
 i++;
}

console.log(string);
```

```html
<div id="tegs_tagsinput" style="display:none">
  <span class="tag"><span>1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
  <span class="tag"><span>2&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
  <span class="tag"><span>3&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```